# Do tennis players require the permission of their country to participate in tournaments?

Tags: tennis, tournaments, participation

Do tennis players need the permission of the governing body of tennis in their respective countries to participate in Grand slams and open competitions? Are the players under the jurisdiction of these organizations?

Also, can the governing body of tennis in a particular country prevent the participation of a player of that country in such tournaments due to any internal reason within the country?

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can participate in any competition as long as they are registered with the [ITF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Tennis_Federation) and they have signed up and received a [PRO IPIN](http://www.itftennis.com/ipin/ipininformation/index.asp). They can represent the country that the currently a legal citizen in. In the rare occurrence that the player has dual citizenship, that player can pick between either country. This always stays up to date because each player has to update their IPIN information every time they register for a tournament.

Now to explain the country permissions. Each country has a [Member National Association](http://www.itftennis.com/media/111963/111963.pdf) which you first go through to gain access into playing in the ITF. Here are the regulations for the Member National Association for the USA:

- **Eligibility for ITF International Team Competitions**

> In compliance with ITF regulations, in order to be endorsed by the
>   USTA into ITF international team competitions, a player shall be a
>   U.S. citizen as evidenced by possession of a valid U.S. passport,
>   Certificate of Naturalization, or other documentation acceptable to
>   the ITF. U.S. citizens who reside in Puerto Rico, U.S. Virgin Islands,
>   American Samoa, Guam, or the Northern Mariana Islands may play either
>   for their respective team or the U.S. international team.Once a player
>   has accepted a nomination for one team, the player may not compete on
>   the other team, unless reinstated.

USA Regulation [Source](http://assets.usta.com/assets/1/15/2012%20FRIEND%20AT%20COURT.pdf)